# Python unpack list for use in formatted string

Tags: python

I have a string that I am dynamically creating based off user input. I am using the .format function in Python to add a list into the string, but I would like to remove the quotes and brackets when printing.

I have tried:

```
return (('{} is {}x effective against {}').format(opponentType, overallHitMultiplier, [str(x) for x in playerTypes]))
```

and

```
return return (('{} is {}x effective against {}').format(opponentType, overallHitMultiplier, playerTypes))
```

which both return a string that looks like this:

`fighting is 2x effective against ['normal', 'ghost']`

but I would like it to return something like:

`fighting is 2x effective against normal, ghost`

The length of the list is variable so I can't just insert the list elements one by one.

Comment: `', '.join(playerTypes)`

Comment: Please, check the desired output as it seems the same as the current output

Comment: yes, sorry, I changed it to reflect what I wanted the output to be like. I just want to remove the quotes and square brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more complete response:

```
def convert_player_types_to_str(player_types):
    n = len(player_types)
    if not n:
        return ''
    if n == 1:
        return player_types[0]
    return ', '.join(player_types[:-1]) + f' and {player_types[-1]}'

>>> convert_player_types_to_str(['normal'])
'normal'

>>> convert_player_types_to_str(['normal', 'ghost'])
'normal and ghost'

>>> convert_player_types_to_str(['normal', 'ghost', 'goblin'])
'normal, ghost and goblin'
```